# How to get payment form data in my observer execute method

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment-methods

i am trying to save the **payment method custom field** in magento2 to payment related table. my observer is triggering but i am not able to get the custom field data.
**observer class**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class PaymentAssignData implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        //die(__METHOD__);
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
         $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_data','custom_field');;
         $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);


    }

}
```

my custom field are added thhrough **LayoutProcessor**.

Comment: Which observer event you tried to catch?

Comment: i am using 'sales_order_save_before' events.

Comment: Try with `$order->getPayment()->getData('custom_field')`?

Comment: already checked,getting null value.

Answer (score 2):

To get payment details Magento already has the observer - `\Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver`.

In most cases it will be enough to extend it:

```
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;

class AdditionalDataReader extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);

        $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);

        if (!is_array($additionalData)) {
            return;
        }
        // your custom code
    }
}
```

On the next step, you need to add created observer to list of events in your module (`CustomModule/etc/events.xml`):

```
<event name="payment_method_assign_data">
    <observer name="additional_data_reader" instance="CustomPayment\Observer\AdditionalDataReader" />
</event>
```

Created observer will be triggered when all data will be set to `additional_data` property (for now, more preferable to use `additional_information`).

But, your custom payment should sent additional properties from Storefront|Admin panel to the backend.

For example, for Storefront your payment component should overrides `getData` method:

```
define(
    ['Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form'],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            // Your component code
            ...
            getData: function () {
                var data = {
                    'method': 'custom_payment_code',
                    'additional_data': {
                        'custom_field': 'some custom data'
                    }
                };

                return data;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**UPD**: [This topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html#getting-payment-information-from-frontend-to-backend) describes how to read payment additional data.

Comment: checked with "payment_method_assign_data" event but its not working.

Comment: in the observer event is not triggering..

Comment: The `payment_method_assign_data` and `payment_method_assign_data_custom_payment_code` are specified in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Method/Adapter.php#L603  or in deprecated Abstract Method https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php#L771

Comment: @jonijones : Please suggest which observer i should call for get the post data of the which is passed in https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/swgx85nh2d5c4kjs/client_api/v1/payment_methods/credit_cards

I mean which observer will be called before this action which happen just after place order button click...

Comment: For Braintree the `\Magento\Braintree\Observer\DataAssignObserver` will be called, it sets all required data from `additional_data` to payment `additionalInformation`

Comment: hello,  i am using paytm method and using payment_method_assign_data_paytm but its not working for me.